# SASS wildcard * to select all ids inside a parent

Tags: sass

I've seen somewhere the ability use * for ID or class selectors with SASS...what is the right way to do this?

For example I want to select all div id's inside a parent div. I would imagine something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
                <div id="sub1">
                    <div class="icon"></div>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="sub2">
                    <div class="icon"></div>
                    <div class="content"></div>
                </div>

#parent {
   #* {
}}
```

Comment: Sass has no such wildcard, but CSS *does*.  Sass also only knows what CSS knows regarding your document's markup (in other words:  nothing).  Could you rephrase your question?  Because it is unclear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you be specific about why the simple CSS selectors `#parent *` or `#parent div` wouldn't work?

Comment: yes, i was a bit unclear, sorry, i have update my intended code above.
basically i want to select #sub1 and #sub2. so * and div wont work (because then it will select the others) however, #parent > div *would* work, i was just hoping for a sassy way to do this :D i will try to the answer below posted by bookcasey and post back!

Comment: Again, for that example you can use `#parent > div` (plain CSS) to select only direct descendants.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the children are named in an orderly fashion, you could make it easier to update using the `@for` directive:

```
$num-of-children: 2

@for $i from 1 through $num-of-children
  #sub-#{$i}
    @extend %parent-children

#parent
  %parent-children
    //styles
```

In addition, if the ids are more arbitrary, you can pass a list into the `@each` directive to achieve a similar effect:

```
$children: sam ramond lemons butter

@each $child in $children
  ##{$child} 
    @extend %parent-children

#parent
  %parent-children
    //styles
```

Comment: Thanks, thats very interesting code! however, i should have been more specific in saying that my sub divs are not actually numbered, they all have unique ID names. however, this is nice stuff and i will keep it in mind. ideas how to use it for sub divs with unique id names?
i am using SCSS so i formatted this for that - here is the sample and the output.

`$num-of-children: 2;

@for $i from 1 through $num-of-children {
  #sub-#{$i}{
    @extend %parent-children }
}
#parent
  %parent-children {
    background: blue;
}`

`#parent #sub-1, #toolbar #parent #sub-2 {
    background: blue; }` (edit?)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a similar option for unique names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use only a css selector, like it:

```
#parent {
    div[id] {
      // styles
    }
}
```

or

```
#parent {
    div[id^='sub'] {
      // styles
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thats very cool! could you elaborate a little bit what is the `div[id^='sub']`...the ^ is a wildcard for anything after 'sub'?

Comment: @petergus Ya! there are more selector like that, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors